# Crop pdf by given coordinates using .net

Tags: c#, api, pdf, crop

I want to crop pdf by given coordinates using c#.

How can I do it? What are API/Libraries I can use? (Doesn't matter commercial or not but I can't spent lot)

Comment: I think you're just looking for a pdf to image conversion lib, with an image you'll be able to crop with coordinates easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) has the option to crop pages by manipulating directly the page's CropBox or by extracting the page content and cropping it using a clip region.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can do exactly what you want, but [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.com/) is a free and open source library for creating PDF files in .NET. I can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ is one that I've used before that I am pretty sure will do what you need.  Will find some source code later if I have time.

Comment: iText[sharp] will do it, but isn't particularly cheap.  OTOH, if you can live with AGPL, it's Free.  Older versions (pre 5.0) of iText[sharp] are MPL/LGPL, and are free for commercial use.